# Grammatik in "wenn es dort welchen gibt"

Tags: grammar, pronoun

Aus der [Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/wirtschaftspolitik/stromerzeugung-deutschland-braucht-die-kohlekraftwerke-13273398.html):

> Vom Winter 2018/19 an kann laut Gabriel in der kalten Jahreszeit der größtmögliche Strombedarf nicht mehr aus heimischer Erzeugung gedeckt werden. Dann würde Strom (Kohle? Atom?) aus dem Ausland benötigt, **wenn es dort welchen gibt**.

Ich verstehe, dass sich *welchen* auf *Strom* bezieht. Was ich aber nicht verstehe, ist, warum es *welchen* ist statt *den*. Warum das Fragewort?

Comment: "Welchen" bedeutet hier etwa "etwas davon" gibt, der Grund ist, dass "Strom" hier unzählbar benutzt wird.

Comment: Strom braucht ein Indefinitpronomen, weil man nicht einen bestimmten, bekannten Strom individuell kaufen kann, sondern eben nur eine bestimmte Menge. Gegenbeispiel wären z.B. Fußballspieler, die extrem individuell und bekannt sind: "Wir sollten Diego Maradona kaufen, wenn es **den** noch gibt."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das Pronomen *welcher* kann verschiedene Funktionen übernehmen:

- **[Fragepronomen  (Interrogativpronomen)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/welcher_wen_wer)**: „***Welcher*** Mantel ist Deiner?“
- **[Relativpronomen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/welcher_welch_der_dieser_jener)**: „Das ist die Kreuzung, an ***welcher*** wir abbiegen müssen.“ <sup>(Beispiel [von canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-welch.html))</sup>
  (stilistisch nicht so schön, besser: „…, an ***der*** wir …“)
- **[Indefinitpronomen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/welcher_einige_etliche)**: „Ich habe Milch gekauft. Es müsste noch ***welche*** im Kühlschrank stehen.“ <sup>(Beispiel [von canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-welch.html))</sup>

Im Beispiel wird „welcher“ jedenfalls nicht in seiner Funktion als Fragepronomen benutzt. Ich würde hier einen Fall der Nutzung als Indefinitpronomen sehen, da nicht von einer bestimmten „Menge“ Strom gesprochen wird, sondern von ***Strom als Stoffbezeichnung***; zudem ist es nicht sicher, ob es überhaupt Strom zu kaufen gibt. Da Strom hier als Stoffbezeichnung - quasi als Gattungsbegriff - verwendet wird, kann an dieser Stelle kein bestimmtes, definites Pronomen („*den*“) stehen (siehe [Kilians Kommentar zur Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18504/grammatik-in-wenn-es-dort-welchen-gibt/18508#comment43110_18504)).

Comment: Zwar sagt man es so nicht, aber "wennwelchen" wäre ein offensichtlich zusammengesetztes Fragewort. Der unterschiedliche Satzbau schadet dem nicht. Wenn man will, kann man vorraussetzen, die Ausgangsform des Fragewortes sei "Welchen Strom gibt es?", "Welchen _ gibt es?" und "Gibt es welchen" davon abgrenzen, aber man kann doch vergleichen "Gibt es, welchen wir wollen?" und demnach im Bsp ebenso anschließen, "... welchen gibt, den wir wollen". Eventuell liegt da die Crux. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob das sonst in der Antwort überhaupt angeschnitten werden sollte.